# How to set missing some columns and their corresponding columns in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a longitudinal data with three follow-up. The columns 2,3 and 4
I want to set the value 99 in the columns v_9, v_01, and v_03 to NA, but I want to set their corresponding columns (columns "d_9", "d_01","d_03" and "a_9", "a_01","a_03") as NA as well. As an example for ID 101 as below:
How can I do this for all the individuals and my whole data set in R? thanks in advance for the help.

```
"id"  "v_9" "v_01" "v_03"     "d_9"     "d_01"    "d_03"       "a_9"      "a_01"   "a_03"
  101   12     NA      10    2015-03-23    NA     2003-06-19   40.50650     NA     44.1065

  

structure(list(id = c(101, 102, 103, 104), v_9 = c(12, 99, 16, 
25), v_01 = c(99, 12, 16, NA), v_03 = c(10, NA, 99, NA), d_9 = structure(c(16517, 
17613, 16769, 10667), class = "Date"), d_01 = structure(c(13291, 
NA, 13566, NA), class = "Date"), d_03 = structure(c(12222, NA, 
12119, NA), class = "Date"), a_9 = c(40.5065, 40.5065, 30.19713, 
51.40862), a_01 = c(42.5065, 41.5112, 32.42847, NA), a_03 = c(44.1065, 
NA, 35.46543, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
fn <- function(df){
    for(s in c("_9" , "_01" , "_03")){
        i <- which(`[[`(df,paste0("v",s)) == 99)
        df[i, paste0("v",s)] <- NA
        df[i, paste0("d",s)] <- NA
        df[i, paste0("a",s)] <- NA
    }
    df
}

df <- fn(df)
```

###### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 10
     id   v_9  v_01  v_03 d_9        d_01       d_03         a_9  a_01  a_03
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   101    12    NA    10 2015-03-23 NA         2003-06-19  40.5  NA    44.1
2   102    NA    12    NA NA         NA         NA          NA    41.5  NA  
3   103    16    16    NA 2015-11-30 2007-02-22 NA          30.2  32.4  NA  
4   104    25    NA    NA 1999-03-17 NA         NA          51.4  NA    NA
```

Comment: what double [[ means in the line below:                                                                           
                                                  i <- which(`[[`(df,paste0("v",s)) == 99)

Comment: could you please explain the line three with double  [[

Comment: @ Mohamed Desouky if I want to do this for many columns what can I write instead of the last three lines in the for loop? Is there a short way to write this?

Comment: ``[[`` same as `df[[paste0("v",s)]]` , since every thing in `R` is function you can use `[[` as function with two arguments , first data.frame and the second the name of the column , this could should work with any number of columns have the same conventions in you question .

Comment: @
Mohamed Desouky thanks. this means that I can write instead: i = which([[(df,paste0("v",s)) == 99)]], right?

Comment: Like this `i = which(df[[paste0("v",s)]] == 99)`